# How do I translate "나는 네가 노력한 것을 닮아야만 한다"?

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

How can I translate the sentence
"나는 네가 노력한 것을 닮아야만 한다"
into English?

I suppose it means something like "I have to live up to your expectations as you have invested a lot of time in me"

Is there a better translation into English that matches what the sentence says?

Comment: The original Korean sentence is blatantly wrong, so there cannot be a meaningful translation for that sentence. I also wonder where you saw that sentence. If you give me the context in which the sentence is used, then I can make a better guess and will let you know.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds very weird.  No native Korean speaker would utter such a sentence.  I suspect that someone did a poor translation from English.

Comment: The sentence sounds completely natural to myself, a native speaker, given a certain context. Fortunately, both answers catch it.

Answer (score 2):

I would be interested to know where this sentence came from.

If I was translating this sentence, I would probably write it as follows (several options):

> Even as you have tried, so too must I try.
>
> My efforts will be as your efforts have been.
>
> All I can do is try as you have tried.

The VS + 아/어/여 야만 form in my mind implies a feeling of "all one can do," or "the only thing one can do."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can this sentence be broken down? What does 노력한것을 닮다 mean? That is, what does the presence of 을 imply here?

Comment: The object marker on 노력한것 is associated with the 야하다 part of the sentence. It indicates *what*(so an object)  is imperative.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is said when someone achieves a great success and the other person is giving compliment or credit for the effort which led to that person's success.

Here's a scenario.

Person A wasn't born with a singing talent. Person B was born with an amazing singing talent. Both Person A and Person B participated in a singing contest.

Person A practiced hard everyday because he knows he doesn't have much talent to win in that competition.
Person B didn't practice much as he trusted his natural-born talent and was sure he would win in that competition.

In the end, Person A won the award for Best Singing Talent from the singing contest instead of Person B.

In this case, Person B says to Person A with admiration :

> "I must follow the example of your (hard) effort"
>
> 나는 네가 노력한 것을 닮아야만 한다.